# Table deadlock issues with lock escalations

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-deadlocks

I have a table where anywhere between 1 and 5 million records come in as a batch and then a bunch of stored procedures are ran on them that update and delete records in the batch.
All of these stored procedures are using two fields for selectivity so they only run on the records in that batch.
Both of these fields are in a nonclustered index.
There are times when multiple batches are run at the same time and I am continuously getting deadlocks happening between batches, I assume due to lock escalations.
Trying to figure out if there is a way to solve this without a complete redesign to use a dedicated table for each batch. Is disabling page locks asking for more trouble?

Additional information:

Example of table structure and Index(the real one has a lot more columns than this)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TempImport](
    [UID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [EID] [int] NULL,
    [EXTID] [int] NULL,
    [COL1] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [COL2] [varchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TempImport] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [UID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_TempImport_Main] ON [dbo].[TempImport]
(
    [EID] ASC,
    [EXTID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

And the types of queries in the stored procedures look something like this:

```
update TempImport set COL1 = 'foo' where EID = @EID and EXTID = @EXT and COL2='bar'
```

And the last thing that happens when batch completes is something like this:

```
Delete from TempImport where EID = @EID and EXTID = @EXT
```

It is typically the delete and the updates in the stored procedures that are involved in the deadlock.

Please let me know if any other info would be useful

Comment: Using MS SQL 2019

Comment: Brent Ozar recently did a [nice video on deadlocks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bjS_ORPKh10). It may have some ideas for this. It is 45 mins but I found it helped to understand them and how to fix them. As you say, it is likely that tables are locked - I believe that if SQL Server is updating more than 5000 rows in a table it will escalate the lock to a full table lock. One thing I wasn't clear about from the video, was whether doing the batch in a transactions (or several smaller transactions) would overcome the deadlocks.

Comment: Thanks I will take a look at that video. That is one thought I had was to somehow break up the updates and deletes into smaller chunks but that seems like it would be much less efficient when dealing with millions of records.

Answer (score 0):

Just some potential suggestions

- Yeah, you could split them up into (say) batches of 2000, to stop the row locks escalating to table locks, but you'd have a gazillion running. Probably not a good solution.
- You could modify the update processes (as per [Brent Ozar's video re deadlocks I recommended in the comments](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bjS_ORPKh10)) to update each table once and once only. As a suggestion, you could also try encapsulating them in transactions. These could remove deadlocks, but add blocking (where the second operation has to wait for the first to finish).
- A structural method is to make a 'loading' or 'scratch' table which has IDs and relevant data to be operated on (you could see this as a queue). When calls to do updates come in, they simply insert their requests into that queue. Then you have an asynchronous process (that can only be called one at a time) that gets all outstanding data from the queue (and flags it as such), does the relevant processing, then cleans out the processed data from the scratch table.

Note that if you have other things accessing/using this table, then they could get blocked or deadlocked on this table too, and then your approach needs to be very careful.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, I am going to do some testing with the second option you suggest since it seems like it is the least disruptive. Within reason I am ok with blocking and the queries taking a little longer to avoid deadlocks.

Comment: FWIW I figured I would update with what we ended up doing. Not a perfect solution but its working for us. 
We modified the all of our stored procs to copy the data to a temp table and then run all of the rules in the temp table. We then update all of the data back to the main table and have added deadlock retry code on that update.

Comment: That seems reasonable - indeed, is a good strategy to minimise the effect on the live table. Doing all the multiple data updates on the temp table to prepare it to what you need, then just applying the changes in one or two commands, is a good method imo. One thing most people don't realise, is that you can put primary keys on temporary tables. If you have the same primary key on the temp table as the final table, then it could make make the inserts/updates quicker as the indexes match (the data is already pre-sorted correctly).